# How to store an array values in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, html-table

Values submitted by a form are stored in $array.

```
$array= array("123","James","New York");
```

*MySQL table(Customer)*

```
ID-----NAME-----CITY
```

I am new to PHP.I want to **insert** the array data into relevant columns in the MySQL table.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (ID,NAME,CITY) 
                    VALUES ('123','James','New York')" );
```

can be used however the number of array elements can change in each form submission.

How can I do it using **PHP**?

**Note:**

In select table page the user selects the table from the drop down menu then the customized form is loaded. So the Column names depend on the table the user selects. I can get the values submitted in the form in "$array". But  the problem is number of values change each time.

**mysql_query(INSERT INTO customer VALUES ($array)); //this format cannot be used**

**Select table code**

```
<?php
include("functions.inc");
connectDatabase();
$queryseltable= "SHOW TABLES" or die("error query");

$result=mysql_query($queryseltable);


?>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form action="process.php" method="post">

<div id="wrapper">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="right">Select Table:</td>
        <td id="input">

        <select name="table">

        <?php

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


            extract($row);
            echo "<option>".$Tables_in_database ."</option>";        
        }
        ?>

        </select>

        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Select" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>

</form>
<?php
?>
```

**Process.php code**

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

<?php

include("functions.inc");

connectDatabase();

$table= $_POST['table'];

$_SESSION['table'] = $table;

$query= "SELECT * FROM $table";

$result= mysql_query($query) or die("query failed");

$count=mysql_num_fields($result);

$fieldname = mysql_field_name($result, 0);

?>

<div id="wrapper">

    <table>

        <?php

        for($x=0; $x<$count;$x++){

                $fieldname = mysql_field_name($result, $x);
        echo "  
                <tr>
                     <td id=\"right\">$fieldname</td>
                     <td id=\"input\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"test[]\" /></td>
                </tr>
      ";


      }

      ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Insert" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: what does your form look like?  Have you tried doing a print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323161/creating-a-dynamic-php-insert-into-mysql-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use PDO prepared statements, like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dns); // where $dns is your connection string
$q = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO customer (ID, NAME, CITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$q->execute(array("123","James","New York"));
```

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) about PDO

**Updated:**

If you really need this, you can pass array through POST, like

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="table[column1]" value="value1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="table[column2]" value="value2" />
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="table[columnN]" value="valueN" />
</form>
```

with named columns, because your form generating when you KNOW what the columns are.

In PHP you would get:

```
$array = $_POST['table'];
// Now, $array === array('column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2', ..., 'columnN' => 'valueN');
```

And you can do this:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dns); // where $dns is your connection string
$q = $pdo->prepare(sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO customer (%s) VALUES (%s)',
    implode(', ', array_keys($array)), // column names separated by ', '
    implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($array), '?')) // ? marks for placing values
));
$q->execute($array);
```

Hope that helps you some how. **But SHOULD KNOW THAT THIS WAY IS VEERY UNSECURED, PLEASE DO NOT THIS UNTIL YOU REALLY NEED IT**

Comment: Nice, intelligent solution +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$insert = null;
foreach($array as $pos => $value) {
    $mysql_value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $your_mysql_connection);
    $insert_query = ($pos > 0 ? ',', '').'\''.$mysql_value.'\'';
}

mysql_query('INSERT INTO customer (ID,NAME,CITY) 
                VALUES ('.$insert_query.')' );
```

Answer (score 2):

well say you could use **array_keys()**:

```
array array_keys ( array $input [, mixed $search_value = NULL [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

to get array keys, which should correspond fields' names in your table,

then using **implode()**

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

convert array of keys to string, then convert original array to string to get fields values, like this:

```
$myArray = array('A', 'B', 'C');

echo "'" . implode("','", $myArray) . "'"; //Displays 'A', 'B', 'C'
```

then insert it into your query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer ($keys) 
                    VALUES ($values)" );
```

Answer (score 2):

That's silly. How can the number of array elements change? If it's a form, then it has a static number of fields. Every field can/should correspond to a column in MySQL. If you don't always need all of the columns then you can set their default value to `NULL`, then omit that column on insertion.

Say you have the table:

`id` `name` `city` `email` `favorite_pie`

If these columns are set to `ALLOW NULL`, you can run these inserts:

```
INSERT INTO customer (id,name,city) VALUES ('123','James','New York');
INSERT INTO customer (id,name,email) VALUES ('234','John','foo@bar.com');
INSERT INTO customer (id,email,favorite_pie) VALUES ('345','Carl','Cherry');
```

And all omitted fields will be set to NULL.

---

But if you **need** to store an array, you can always serialize it and store it as text. You can do that in PHP as follows:

```
serialize(array("123","James","New York"));
```

That will produce the following string:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:3:"123";i:1;s:5:"James";i:2;s:8:"New York";}
```

You can save that string in a text or varchar field. Upon retrieval you can unserialize it like this to get the array:

```
$myArray = unserialize($theString);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the array is matching the columns, probably something like this:

```
// The array previously filled somewhere above, having currently these values

$array = array("123","James","New York");

// Escaping values
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    $array[$i] = "'{$array[$i]}'";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (ID,NAME,CITY) 
                VALUES (" . implode(', ', $array) . ")" );
```

However, this may lead to security issues.

Comment: please escape your string first for a +1

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through array as shown below :-

```
$array= array("123","James","New York");
for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++)
    {
        $id = $array[$i][5];
        $name = $array[$i][10];
        $city = $array[$i][13];

        // Run query using the variable values rather than the array values.
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (ID,NAME,CITY) 
                       VALUES ($id,$name,$city)" );

    }
```